# How to switch between the forms without creating new instance of forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

in my windows form application i have two forms Form1 and Form2 , and a single button in each form to switch between the forms, how can i implement this without creating new instance of forms

Form 1:

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.Show();
}
```

Form 2:

```
private void Previous_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Hide();
     Form1 form = new Form1();
     form.Show();
}
```

Comment: What is " ads data "?

Comment: its an communication protocol for beckoff plc

Comment: If "beckoff plc" and "ads data" is relevant then update the question tags to show that the question requires knowledge of this.  If not, remove it from the question.

Comment: in my windows form application i have two forms Form1 and Form2 , and a single button in each form to switch between the forms, how can i implement this without creating new instance of forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like rather than switch between forms, you're actually creating a new one each time.  So when you go back from Form2 to Form1, you're actually going to a new instance of Form1 (the original instance of Form1 is still hidden)  This would explain why the data is not updated when you go back.

Comment: how to implement without creating new instance of forms show and hide the forms

Comment: Well that's an entirely different question altogether.  Each form needs to be aware of the other, so you can do that in a number of ways.  For example when Form1 creates Form2, it could pass a reference to itself to Form2.  Form2 would then just show this instead of creating a new one etc....

Comment: Something like (no time for proper code):

Add a property to each form called OtherForm, of the appropriate type (Form1 or Form2).

before calling the other form check that property.  If it is null, create the form and store it in that property.  If it is not null (ie. you already created it), just show it.

The idea here is that each form maintains a reference to the other one. A new form gets created the first time, but from that point onwards it just shows the one it created last time.

Or the code that creates Form1 in the first place could create both and set the properties(probably best)